# How to convert g/L to mol/L

Tags: concentration, stoichiometry, units

I know I should divide $\pu{g L-1}$ by the molar mass of the substance, but I don't seem to find the specific answer on Google. So just to be sure:

If I have $10^{-5}~\pu{g L-1}~\ce{Cu^2+}$ solution, do I have $1.57 \times 10^{-7}~\pu{mol L-1}$?

I think I'm missing something.

Comment: Dimensional analysis is helpful. g/L divided by g/mol gives mol/L.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. $$n = \frac{m}{M}~~~~~~~~~~n = cV$$
So $$c = \frac{m}{VM}$$

Given $\frac{m}{V}$ you can work out $c$ (in $\mathrm{mol~dm^{-3}}$).

Answer (score 0):

Grams of $\ce{Cu^{+2}}$ is ill defined.  The $\ce{Cu^{+2}}$ did not get into the solution by itself. It was $\ce{CuCl2,CuSO4}$ or some other salt.

This is probably the reason for the discrepancy.

Comment: What discrepancy? The OP's question seems perfectly clear to me.

Comment: The OP is mentioning a different answer compared to "the specific answer on google". That is what I meant by `discrepancy`